# Class name for unix-like permission object

Tags: java, class, permissions, acl

I have a class to store unix-like permissions for user, group and other. In principle it is a limited access control list but I don't want to name it ACL, because usually an ACL is something different.

The class looks basically like this:

```
class X {
  boolean userRead, userWrite, userExecute;
  boolean groupRead, groupWrite, groupExecute;
  boolean otherRead, otherWrite, otherExecute;
}
```

How to name a class like this? What is the name in Unix?

Comment: You're aware this isn't complete, right? (sticky, setuid, setgid, ...)

Comment: Good hint! Actually the class is only in my brain until now and the details are missing ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often for such questions, the answer is in the question. I would call it `Permissions` with a comment above saying "Unix-like permissions for user, group, and other".

Comment: UnixPermissions would be a better name, since permissions on Windows work differently (this is a java class, right?).

Comment: Sure, 'UnixPermissions' might be fine, though that might lead to 'UnixLikePermissions' or a qualifying comment of why they are not _really_ Unix permissions, which are less clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it deals strictly with file permissions, so what about calling it `FilePermissions`?

Comment: It is not limited to files. A secured object could also be a row in a data base table. But maybe simply "Permissions" would be a good name.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with `class permission_bits { }`, probably in a `package unix`.

Comment: That would be PermissionBits according to the usual Java conventions. Just to distinguish the identifier from a method name.

Answer (score 0):

1) PermissionStatus
2) st_mode see http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Permission-Bits.html#Permission-Bits